# Input type='text' element not taking spaces

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I need to allow white spaces to be added up in text box. This text box is a dynamically added by jquery for renaming purpose. But problem is it is not allowing white spaces to enter. Please suggest.

```
    <li><a id='tab" + RenameCounter + "' class='Clickable' href='#{href}' onclick='JavaScript:ShowMiniDialog(this);'>#{label}</a><input type= 'text' id='Rename" + RenameCounter + "' style='display:none;'/></li>
```

this part is dynamically adding up. On double click i am showing the text box to rename the jquery tab.  But i dont know why it is not allowing to enter white spaces. !!!

```
     var tabheader = $('#tabs').find("li");
            tabheader.dblclick('tabsselect', function (event) {
                var selectedTab = $("#tabs").tabs('option', 'active');

                var rid = "input[id=Rename1]";

                $("#tabs ul li a").eq(selectedTab).hide();
                $(rid).val($("#tabs ul li a").eq(selectedTab).text());
                $(rid).css('display', '');
                $(rid).focus();
                $(rid).bind('blur', function () {
                    var newtext = $(rid).val();

                    var selectedTab = $("#tabs").tabs('option', 'active');                       
                    $("#tabs ul li a").eq(selectedTab).text(newtext);
                    $("#spantablistitem1").text(newtext);
                    $(rid).css('display', 'none');
                    $("#tabs ul li a").eq(selectedTab).show();

                });
            });
```

One thing i noticed is that textbox is not behaving as expected when it is inside the        'li' tag element. Please suggest some workaround. Since it is working correctly when it is outside the 'li' tag element !!!!

Comment: please share all relevant javascript.

Comment: i have shared javascript @DanielA.White

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a jsfiddle and does firebug says anything?

Comment: typo? `var rid = "input[id=Rename1"]";` a double quote missing and unescaped

Comment: that one by mistake. i edited it @user3153169.

Comment: try changing `"input[id=Rename1]"` to `"input[id='Rename1']"` (adding single quotes around `Rename1`)

Comment: @Bharadwaj I have added some more details in question. Same thing is working when it is outside the li element. problem is li with textbox. here arrow keys and space is completely disabled.

Comment: @Chethan Have you tried by changing `"input[id=Rename1]"` to `"input[id='Rename1']"`?

Comment: @Bharadwaj i tried that too but not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem... impossible to use space bar in my input field ...

Try to put that at the end of your code :

```
$('Rename1').on('keydown', function (e) {
          e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Comment: where do i need to add this function. It is breaking tab styles.